# ¿Cómo modificar en un gráfico de líneas, los atributos de una de las lineas en particular?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tengo un `data.frame` parecido al siguiente:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:60, y=runif(60), grupo=c("A", "B"))
```

La forma clásica de hacer un gráfico de lineas es está:

```
library("tidyverse")

ggplot(data=df) + 
  geom_line(mapping=aes(x=x, y=y, color=grupo)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, el problema, es que quisiera "customizar" una de la lineas, es decir, modificar sus atributos, por ejemplo el tamaño del trazo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma también clásica, es "mapear" los atributos de la línea a partir de los datos, de la siguiente forma:

```
ggplot(data=df) + 
  geom_line(mapping=aes(x=x, y=y, color=grupo, size=grupo)) +
  scale_size_manual(values=c(.5, 1)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Agregamos el `mapping` `size=grupo` y establecemos manualmente con `scale_size_manual()`  el tamaño del trazo de cada linea.

Otra forma interesante, que en algunos casos puede ser cómoda, es tratar cada grupo por separado y manejar el tamaño por afuera del `mapping`:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=filter(df, grupo=="A"), mapping=aes(x=x, y=y, color=grupo), size = .5) +
  geom_line(data=filter(df, grupo=="B"), mapping=aes(x=x, y=y, color=grupo), size = 1) +
  theme_minimal()
```

En este caso generamos dos líneas independientes a partir de la separación de cada grupo desde los mismos datos mediante `filter()`.

El resultado en ambos casos es idéntico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo único que varía son las leyendas, cuando ajustamos el tamaño mediante el `mapping` el tamaño de la línea se refleja también en la leyenda, cosa que no ocurre si el `size` lo ajustamos por afuera del `mapping`.